# Connecting using TLS 1.2

Tags: .net, ssl, tls1.2

I have a .NET console app with talk to a WCF service.  The WCF service then makes a webservice call to an external provider.  The external provider is about to turn off support for anything below TLS 1.2

Both of my applications are using .NET framework 4.6 which I believe will automatically negotiate the highest security protocol

The external provider says I am still communicating in TLS 1.0

I have installed fiddler onto one of our app servers to try and see what is happening, here is a screen shot

[image]

I'm new to fiddler, is that saying that my client app is attempting to connect in TLS 1.2 but the server responded with TLS 1.0?

Comment: Yes, you're correct. I'm not sure if what you're seeing is accurate though because Fiddler is MITM-ing the connection. Use Wireshark, not fiddler.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [.Net Framework 4.6.1 not defaulting to TLS 1.2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43872575/net-framework-4-6-1-not-defaulting-to-tls-1-2)

Comment: If your site is on Internet, use SSL Labs to check exactly what protocols it supports ( https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/analyze.html )

Comment: In my experience, even with .NET 4.6 you'll need to set some TLS registry keys to get TLS 1.2 working.  We recently wrote about it here: http://blog.thelevelup.com/pci-security-is-your-restaurant-ready/ You can download [TLS Patcher](https://github.com/TheLevelUp/pos-tls-patcher) from GitHub to help with config.

Comment: In addition to Wireshark you can also use Microsoft Netmon to verify TLS version negotiation.  Here's a tutorial for using Netmon to verify TLS version and applying TLS config:  http://blog.thelevelup.com/pci-security-is-your-restaurant-ready/

Answer (score 0):

I would not recommend using Fiddler to debug TLS version negotiation because Fiddler is a Man-in-the-Middle (MITM) proxy. I.e., your app is connecting to Fiddler and not the service you're attempting to debug.

A better solution is to use a tool such as [Wireshark](https://www.wireshark.org/) or [Microsoft Network Monitor](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=4865) (aka Netmon) to inspect the TLS packets and view the [SSL/TLS handshake](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/kaushal/2013/08/02/ssl-handshake-and-https-bindings-on-iis/).

This [article](http://blog.thelevelup.com/pci-security-is-your-restaurant-ready/) covers using Netmon to determine if your app is attempting to use TLS 1.2 and also covers configuring Windows to use TLS 1.2.