# Issue with OAuth2 returning now Access_denied

Tags: linkedin-api

I'm using Linkedin SSO on my website for more than a year now it has always performed as ask, until today. My website is an ASP.NET MVC5 website (C#). I use the classic Oauth2 integration and everything was working fine until yesterday when I changed the domain of my website. I changed in the developer interface the redirect urls (or should I say I added new url redirects) by it always sends access_denied to my callback url and I don't understand why. Has anyone the same issue these days or tips on how I can correct that issue.

Thanks a lot for your help

Answer (score 2):

We had the same issue and after a bit of digging it appears that LinkedIn is now forcing tls1.2 - if you are on an old framework - you may have to upgrade - 4.6+ has tls1.2 as default and should work with no extra setup (although depending on the server you're running on you may still need to set up support for TLS 1.2 - follow the instructions in the top answer on this post : [.Net Framework 4.6.1 not defaulting to TLS 1.2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43872575/net-framework-4-6-1-not-defaulting-to-tls-1-2)) .

If you are on 4.5+ you can just tell your code to use Tls1.2 by adding the following command somewhere global (for example when you initialize linkedin auth):

```
ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;
```

Some further info about Tls1.2 and support in .net can be found here : https://blogs.perficient.com/2016/04/28/tsl-1-2-and-net-support/

Hope this all helps!