# Enable TLS 1.2 for specific Ciphers

Tags: .net, ssl, encryption, windows-server-2008, tls1.2

We have a .NET application which calls an API that allows only TLS version 1.2. Server 2008 SP2.

We ran following script on our server:

```
# Copyright 2016, Alexander Hass
# http://www.hass.de/content/setup-your-iis-ssl-perfect-forward-secrecy-and-tls-12
#
# Version 1.7
# - Windows Version compare failed. Get-CimInstance requires Windows 2012 or later.
# Version 1.6
# - OS version detection for cipher suites order.
# Version 1.5
# - Enabled ECDH and more secure hash functions and reorderd cipher list.
# - Added Client setting for all ciphers.
# Version 1.4
# - RC4 has been disabled.
# Version 1.3
# - MD5 has been disabled.
# Version 1.2
# - Re-factored code style and output
# Version 1.1
# - SSLv3 has been disabled. (Poodle attack protection)

Write-Host 'Configuring IIS with SSL/TLS Deployment Best Practices...'
Write-Host '--------------------------------------------------------------------------------'

# Disable Multi-Protocol Unified Hello
New-Item 'HKLM:\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\SecurityProviders\SCHANNEL\Protocols\Multi-Protocol Unified Hello\Server' -Force | Out-Null
New-ItemProperty -path 'HKLM:\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\SecurityProviders\SCHANNEL\Protocols\Multi-Protocol Unified Hello\Server' -name Enabled -value 0 -PropertyType 'DWord' -Force | Out-Null
New-ItemProperty -path 'HKLM:\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\SecurityProviders\SCHANNEL\Protocols\Multi-Protocol Unified Hello\Server' -name 'DisabledByDefault' -value 1 -PropertyType 'DWord' -Force | Out-Null
New-Item 'HKLM:\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\SecurityProviders\SCHANNEL\Protocols\Multi-Protocol Unified Hello\Client' -Force | Out-Null
New-ItemProperty -path 'HKLM:\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\SecurityProviders\SCHANNEL\Protocols\Multi-Protocol Unified Hello\Client' -name Enabled -value 0 -PropertyType 'DWord' -Force | Out-Null
New-ItemProperty -path 'HKLM:\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\SecurityProviders\SCHANNEL\Protocols\Multi-Protocol Unified Hello\Client' -name 'DisabledByDefault' -value 1 -PropertyType 'DWord' -Force | Out-Null
Write-Host 'Multi-Protocol Unified Hello has been disabled.'

# Disable PCT 1.0
New-Item 'HKLM:\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\SecurityProviders\SCHANNEL\Protocols\PCT 1.0\Server' -Force | Out-Null
New-ItemProperty -path 'HKLM:\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\SecurityProviders\SCHANNEL\Protocols\PCT 1.0\Server' -name Enabled -value 0 -PropertyType 'DWord' -Force | Out-Null
New-ItemProperty -path 'HKLM:\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\SecurityProviders\SCHANNEL\Protocols\PCT 1.0\Server' -name 'DisabledByDefault' -value 1 -PropertyType 'DWord' -Force | Out-Null
New-Item 'HKLM:\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\SecurityProviders\SCHANNEL\Protocols\PCT 1.0\Client' -Force | Out-Null
New-ItemProperty -path 'HKLM:\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\SecurityProviders\SCHANNEL\Protocols\PCT 1.0\Client' -name Enabled -value 0 -PropertyType 'DWord' -Force | Out-Null
New-ItemProperty -path 'HKLM:\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\SecurityProviders\SCHANNEL\Protocols\PCT 1.0\Client' -name 'DisabledByDefault' -value 1 -PropertyType 'DWord' -Force | Out-Null
Write-Host 'PCT 1.0 has been disabled.'

# Disable SSL 2.0 (PCI Compliance)
New-Item 'HKLM:\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\SecurityProviders\SCHANNEL\Protocols\SSL 2.0\Server' -Force | Out-Null
New-ItemProperty -path 'HKLM:\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\SecurityProviders\SCHANNEL\Protocols\SSL 2.0\Server' -name Enabled -value 0 -PropertyType 'DWord' -Force | Out-Null
New-ItemProperty -path 'HKLM:\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\SecurityProviders\SCHANNEL\Protocols\SSL 2.0\Server' -name 'DisabledByDefault' -value 1 -PropertyType 'DWord' -Force | Out-Null
New-Item 'HKLM:\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\SecurityProviders\SCHANNEL\Protocols\SSL 2.0\Client' -Force | Out-Null
New-ItemProperty -path 'HKLM:\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\SecurityProviders\SCHANNEL\Protocols\SSL 2.0\Client' -name Enabled -value 0 -PropertyType 'DWord' -Force | Out-Null
New-ItemProperty -path 'HKLM:\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\SecurityProviders\SCHANNEL\Protocols\SSL 2.0\Client' -name 'DisabledByDefault' -value 1 -PropertyType 'DWord' -Force | Out-Null
Write-Host 'SSL 2.0 has been disabled.'

# NOTE: If you disable SSL 3.0 the you may lock out some people still using
# Windows XP with IE6/7. Without SSL 3.0 enabled, there is no protocol available
# for these people to fall back. Safer shopping certifications may require that
# you disable SSLv3.
#
# Disable SSL 3.0 (PCI Compliance) and enable "Poodle" protection
New-Item 'HKLM:\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\SecurityProviders\SCHANNEL\Protocols\SSL 3.0\Server' -Force | Out-Null
New-ItemProperty -path 'HKLM:\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\SecurityProviders\SCHANNEL\Protocols\SSL 3.0\Server' -name Enabled -value 0 -PropertyType 'DWord' -Force | Out-Null
New-ItemProperty -path 'HKLM:\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\SecurityProviders\SCHANNEL\Protocols\SSL 3.0\Server' -name 'DisabledByDefault' -value 1 -PropertyType 'DWord' -Force | Out-Null
New-Item 'HKLM:\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\SecurityProviders\SCHANNEL\Protocols\SSL 3.0\Client' -Force | Out-Null
New-ItemProperty -path 'HKLM:\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\SecurityProviders\SCHANNEL\Protocols\SSL 3.0\Client' -name Enabled -value 0 -PropertyType 'DWord' -Force | Out-Null
New-ItemProperty -path 'HKLM:\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\SecurityProviders\SCHANNEL\Protocols\SSL 3.0\Client' -name 'DisabledByDefault' -value 1 -PropertyType 'DWord' -Force | Out-Null
Write-Host 'SSL 3.0 has been disabled.'

# Add and Enable TLS 1.0 for client and server SCHANNEL communications
New-Item 'HKLM:\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\SecurityProviders\SCHANNEL\Protocols\TLS 1.0\Server' -Force | Out-Null
New-ItemProperty -path 'HKLM:\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\SecurityProviders\SCHANNEL\Protocols\TLS 1.0\Server' -name 'Enabled' -value '0xffffffff' -PropertyType 'DWord' -Force | Out-Null
New-ItemProperty -path 'HKLM:\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\SecurityProviders\SCHANNEL\Protocols\TLS 1.0\Server' -name 'DisabledByDefault' -value 0 -PropertyType 'DWord' -Force | Out-Null
New-Item 'HKLM:\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\SecurityProviders\SCHANNEL\Protocols\TLS 1.0\Client' -Force | Out-Null
New-ItemProperty -path 'HKLM:\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\SecurityProviders\SCHANNEL\Protocols\TLS 1.0\Client' -name 'Enabled' -value '0xffffffff' -PropertyType 'DWord' -Force | Out-Null
New-ItemProperty -path 'HKLM:\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\SecurityProviders\SCHANNEL\Protocols\TLS 1.0\Client' -name 'DisabledByDefault' -value 0 -PropertyType 'DWord' -Force | Out-Null
Write-Host 'TLS 1.0 has been enabled.'

# Add and Enable TLS 1.1 for client and server SCHANNEL communications
New-Item 'HKLM:\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\SecurityProviders\SCHANNEL\Protocols\TLS 1.1\Server' -Force | Out-Null
New-ItemProperty -path 'HKLM:\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\SecurityProviders\SCHANNEL\Protocols\TLS 1.1\Server' -name 'Enabled' -value '0xffffffff' -PropertyType 'DWord' -Force | Out-Null
New-ItemProperty -path 'HKLM:\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\SecurityProviders\SCHANNEL\Protocols\TLS 1.1\Server' -name 'DisabledByDefault' -value 0 -PropertyType 'DWord' -Force | Out-Null
New-Item 'HKLM:\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\SecurityProviders\SCHANNEL\Protocols\TLS 1.1\Client' -Force | Out-Null
New-ItemProperty -path 'HKLM:\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\SecurityProviders\SCHANNEL\Protocols\TLS 1.1\Client' -name 'Enabled' -value '0xffffffff' -PropertyType 'DWord' -Force | Out-Null
New-ItemProperty -path 'HKLM:\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\SecurityProviders\SCHANNEL\Protocols\TLS 1.1\Client' -name 'DisabledByDefault' -value 0 -PropertyType 'DWord' -Force | Out-Null
Write-Host 'TLS 1.1 has been enabled.'

# Add and Enable TLS 1.2 for client and server SCHANNEL communications
New-Item 'HKLM:\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\SecurityProviders\SCHANNEL\Protocols\TLS 1.2\Server' -Force | Out-Null
New-ItemProperty -path 'HKLM:\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\SecurityProviders\SCHANNEL\Protocols\TLS 1.2\Server' -name 'Enabled' -value '0xffffffff' -PropertyType 'DWord' -Force | Out-Null
New-ItemProperty -path 'HKLM:\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\SecurityProviders\SCHANNEL\Protocols\TLS 1.2\Server' -name 'DisabledByDefault' -value 0 -PropertyType 'DWord' -Force | Out-Null
New-Item 'HKLM:\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\SecurityProviders\SCHANNEL\Protocols\TLS 1.2\Client' -Force | Out-Null
New-ItemProperty -path 'HKLM:\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\SecurityProviders\SCHANNEL\Protocols\TLS 1.2\Client' -name 'Enabled' -value '0xffffffff' -PropertyType 'DWord' -Force | Out-Null
New-ItemProperty -path 'HKLM:\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\SecurityProviders\SCHANNEL\Protocols\TLS 1.2\Client' -name 'DisabledByDefault' -value 0 -PropertyType 'DWord' -Force | Out-Null
Write-Host 'TLS 1.2 has been enabled.'

# Re-create the ciphers key.
New-Item 'HKLM:SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\SecurityProviders\SCHANNEL\Ciphers' -Force | Out-Null

# Disable insecure/weak ciphers.
$insecureCiphers = @(
  'DES 56/56',
  'NULL',
  'RC2 128/128',
  'RC2 40/128',
  'RC2 56/128',
  'RC4 40/128',
  'RC4 56/128',
  'RC4 64/128',
  'RC4 128/128'
)
Foreach ($insecureCipher in $insecureCiphers) {
  $key = (Get-Item HKLM:\).OpenSubKey('SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\SecurityProviders\SCHANNEL\Ciphers', $true).CreateSubKey($insecureCipher)
  $key.SetValue('Enabled', 0, 'DWord')
  $key.close()
  Write-Host "Weak cipher $insecureCipher has been disabled."
}

# Enable new secure ciphers.
# - RC4: It is recommended to disable RC4, but you may lock out WinXP/IE8 if you enforce this. This is a requirement for FIPS 140-2.
# - 3DES: It is recommended to disable these in near future. This is the last cipher supported by Windows XP.
# - Windows Vista and before 'Triple DES 168' was named 'Triple DES 168/168' per https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/245030
$secureCiphers = @(
  'AES 128/128',
  'AES 256/256',
  'Triple DES 168'
)
Foreach ($secureCipher in $secureCiphers) {
  $key = (Get-Item HKLM:\).OpenSubKey('SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\SecurityProviders\SCHANNEL\Ciphers', $true).CreateSubKey($secureCipher)
  New-ItemProperty -path "HKLM:\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\SecurityProviders\SCHANNEL\Ciphers\$secureCipher" -name 'Enabled' -value '0xffffffff' -PropertyType 'DWord' -Force | Out-Null
  $key.close()
  Write-Host "Strong cipher $secureCipher has been enabled."
}

# Set hashes configuration.
New-Item 'HKLM:SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\SecurityProviders\SCHANNEL\Hashes' -Force | Out-Null
New-Item 'HKLM:\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\SecurityProviders\SCHANNEL\Hashes\MD5' -Force | Out-Null
New-ItemProperty -path 'HKLM:\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\SecurityProviders\SCHANNEL\Hashes\MD5' -name Enabled -value 0 -PropertyType 'DWord' -Force | Out-Null

$secureHashes = @(
  'SHA',
  'SHA256',
  'SHA384',
  'SHA512'
)
Foreach ($secureHash in $secureHashes) {
  $key = (Get-Item HKLM:\).OpenSubKey('SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\SecurityProviders\SCHANNEL\Hashes', $true).CreateSubKey($secureHash)
  New-ItemProperty -path "HKLM:\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\SecurityProviders\SCHANNEL\Hashes\$secureHash" -name 'Enabled' -value '0xffffffff' -PropertyType 'DWord' -Force | Out-Null
  $key.close()
  Write-Host "Hash $secureHash has been enabled."
}

# Set KeyExchangeAlgorithms configuration.
New-Item 'HKLM:SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\SecurityProviders\SCHANNEL\KeyExchangeAlgorithms' -Force | Out-Null
$secureKeyExchangeAlgorithms = @(
  'Diffie-Hellman',
  'ECDH',
  'PKCS'
)
Foreach ($secureKeyExchangeAlgorithm in $secureKeyExchangeAlgorithms) {
  $key = (Get-Item HKLM:\).OpenSubKey('SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\SecurityProviders\SCHANNEL\KeyExchangeAlgorithms', $true).CreateSubKey($secureKeyExchangeAlgorithm)
  New-ItemProperty -path "HKLM:\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\SecurityProviders\SCHANNEL\KeyExchangeAlgorithms\$secureKeyExchangeAlgorithm" -name 'Enabled' -value '0xffffffff' -PropertyType 'DWord' -Force | Out-Null
  $key.close()
  Write-Host "KeyExchangeAlgorithm $secureKeyExchangeAlgorithm has been enabled."
}

# Set cipher suites order as secure as possible (Enables Perfect Forward Secrecy).
$os = Get-WmiObject -class Win32_OperatingSystem
if ([System.Version]$os.Version -lt [System.Version]'10.0') {
  Write-Host 'Use cipher suites order for Windows 2008/2008R2/2012/2012R2.'
  $cipherSuitesOrder = @(
    'TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384_P521',
    'TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384_P384',
    'TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384_P256',
    'TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256_P521',
    'TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256_P384',
    'TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256_P256',
    'TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA_P521',
    'TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA_P384',
    'TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA_P256',
    'TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA_P521',
    'TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA_P384',
    'TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA_P256',
    'TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384_P521',
    'TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384_P384',
    'TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256_P521',
    'TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256_P384',
    'TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256_P256',
    'TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384_P521',
    'TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384_P384',
    'TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256_P521',
    'TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256_P384',
    'TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256_P256',
    'TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA_P521',
    'TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA_P384',
    'TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA_P256',
    'TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA_P521',
    'TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA_P384',
    'TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA_P256',
    'TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384',
    'TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256',
    'TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256',
    'TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256',
    'TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA',
    'TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA',
    'TLS_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA'
  )
}
else {
  Write-Host 'Use cipher suites order for Windows 10/2016 and later.'
  $cipherSuitesOrder = @(
    'TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384',
    'TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256',
    'TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384',
    'TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256',
    'TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA',
    'TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA',
    'TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384',
    'TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256',
    'TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384',
    'TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256',
    'TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA',
    'TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA',
    'TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384',
    'TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256',
    'TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256',
    'TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256',
    'TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA',
    'TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA',
    'TLS_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA'
  )
}
$cipherSuitesAsString = [string]::join(',', $cipherSuitesOrder)
# One user reported this key does not exists on Windows 2012R2. Cannot repro myself on a brand new Windows 2012R2 core machine. Adding this just to be save.
New-Item 'HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Policies\Microsoft\Cryptography\Configuration\SSL\00010002' -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
New-ItemProperty -path 'HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Policies\Microsoft\Cryptography\Configuration\SSL\00010002' -name 'Functions' -value $cipherSuitesAsString -PropertyType 'String' -Force | Out-Null

Write-Host '--------------------------------------------------------------------------------'
Write-Host 'NOTE: After the system has been rebooted you can verify your server'
Write-Host '      configuration at https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/'
Write-Host "--------------------------------------------------------------------------------`n"

Write-Host -ForegroundColor Red 'A computer restart is required to apply settings. Restart computer now?'
Restart-Computer -Force -Confirm
```

---

But in Wireshark, it shows following in `ClientHello` message. I am not sure why it only supply 7 ciphers here as shown in image. Per script run and priority of ciphers, it should list other protocol as well.

### [image]

Now, server reject the same and API developer mentioned that following are the ciphers that is supported with the API

```
Not allowed ciphers
AES128-GCM-SHA256
ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA
AES128-SHA256

Allowed Ciphers
"ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256"
"ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256"
"ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384"
"ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384"
"ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-SHA384"
"ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA384"
"ECDHE-ECDSA-CHACHA20-POLY1305"
"ECDHE-RSA-CHACHA20-POLY1305"
"ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-SHA256"
"ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA256"
```

Am I missing something?

Comment: Use the [ssllabs.com TLS/SSL server tester](https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/) on your server to find out what ciphersuites it supports. Then you'll know if you configured it correctly.

Comment: James, we have done the test and following is the result. I could not find any SHA256 on windows server 2008 sp2. 
-----------------------------
TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA (0x2f)   WEAK 128
TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA (0x35)   WEAK 256
TLS_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA (0xa)   WEAK 112
TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA (0xc013)   ECDH secp256r1 (eq. 3072 bits RSA)   FS 128
TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA (0xc014)   ECDH secp256r1 (eq. 3072 bits RSA)   FS 256

Answer (score 0):

*Thanks for this question, it helped me - and now this answer as it is working for us.*

=>

Make sure to check all these registry settings

> Computer\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft.NETFramework\v4.0.30319
>
> Computer\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Policies\Microsoft\Cryptography\Configuration\SSL\00010002
>
> Computer\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\SecurityProviders\SCHANNEL\Protocols\TLS1.2\Server

In general, The WCF framework automatically chooses the highest protocol available up to TLS 1.2 unless you explicitly configure a protocol version. But calling REST API might have a different behavior although we have not noticed that.

This was not required in our case:

```
ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls12
```

But this was:

```
<system.web>
    <compilation targetFramework="4.6" />
    <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.6" />
    <customErrors mode="Off" />   </system.web>
```

As well as this one:

```
<basicHttpBinding>
        <binding name="HTTPSEndpoint" messageEncoding="Text">
          <security mode="Transport">
            <transport clientCredentialType="None" proxyCredentialType="None" />
          </security>
        </binding>
```

Hope this helps.

References:

> [Enable TLS 1.2 for specific Ciphers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51151879/enable-tls-1-2-for-specific-ciphers)
>
> [.Net Framework 4.6.1 not defaulting to TLS 1.2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43872575/net-framework-4-6-1-not-defaulting-to-tls-1-2)
>
> https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/network-programming/tls
> https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/friis/2017/10/09/troubleshooting-tls-ssl-scenario-2/
> https://textslashplain.com/2015/10/12/viewing-https-handshakes-in-fiddler/