# Issue during calling REST request via TLS 1.2 protocol

Tags: .net, vb.net, tls1.2

I am trying to inplement REST request via TLS 1.2 protocol and getting issue:

> The request was aborted: Could not create SSL/TLS secure channel

1) Application is hosted on Windows 2016 server

2) Register has enabled server and client configuration enabled in  HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\SecurityProviders\SCHANNEL\Protocols\TLS 1.2  folder

3) Application forced to use TLS protocol

> ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls12

4)  Application is running on .Net 4.7

I would be appropritiate with any ideas

Thanks

Comment: .net *or* VBA, but not both?  Are you using VB.NET ?

Comment: Correct, VB.Net

Comment: Have you tried it adding a the callback that validates the Server certificate(s): [ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.servicepointmanager.servercertificatevalidationcallback) (you usually test it just returning `true`).

Answer (score 0):

Make sure to check all these registry settings

> Computer\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft.NETFramework\v4.0.30319
>
> Computer\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Policies\Microsoft\Cryptography\Configuration\SSL\00010002
>
> Computer\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\SecurityProviders\SCHANNEL\Protocols\TLS1.2\Server

In general, The WCF framework automatically chooses the highest protocol available up to TLS 1.2 unless you explicitly configure a protocol version. But calling REST API might have a different behavior although we have not noticed that.

This was not required in our case:

```
ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls12
```

But this was:

```
<system.web>
    <compilation targetFramework="4.6" />
    <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.6" />
    <customErrors mode="Off" />   </system.web>
```

As well as this one:

```
<basicHttpBinding>
        <binding name="HTTPSEndpoint" messageEncoding="Text">
          <security mode="Transport">
            <transport clientCredentialType="None" proxyCredentialType="None" />
          </security>
        </binding>
```

Hope this helps.

References:

> [Enable TLS 1.2 for specific Ciphers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51151879/enable-tls-1-2-for-specific-ciphers)
>
> [.Net Framework 4.6.1 not defaulting to TLS 1.2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43872575/net-framework-4-6-1-not-defaulting-to-tls-1-2)
>
> https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/network-programming/tls
> https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/friis/2017/10/09/troubleshooting-tls-ssl-scenario-2/
> https://textslashplain.com/2015/10/12/viewing-https-handshakes-in-fiddler/